# Cookie “_ga” will be soon rejected because it has the “SameSite” attribute set to “None” without the “secure” attribute

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, react-gtm-module

I have added Google Tag manager to my react project, with the help of [react-gtm-module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-gtm-module)

After successfully adding it, I see some warning in consoles which are below like -

> Cookie “_ga” will be soon rejected because it has the “SameSite”
> attribute set to “None” or an invalid value, without the “secure”
> attribute.

> Cookie “_gid” will be soon rejected because it has the “SameSite”
> attribute set to “None” or an invalid value, without the “secure”
> attribute.

> Cookie “_gat_UA-xxxxxxxx” will be soon rejected because it has the
> “SameSite” attribute set to “None” or an invalid value, without the
> “secure” attribute.

I see that I have to use sameSite attribute to secure, but how do I implement this with the given library I am using?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't an issue with `react-gtm-module` or it's configuration in your code, it's an issue within Google Tag Manager. Google Analytics tracking cookies provided by GTM don't have a valid `SameSite` attribute.

Note that those warnings only show in certain browsers (e.g. Firefox). As of Update 80, Google Chrome defaults any cookies without a correct `SameSite` value to to `SameSite=Lax` (which might result in them not working properly).

Ideally, the Google Tag Manager team would update their code to automatically set the `SameSite` attributes for cookies. However, you *can* set this yourself:

1. In Google Tag Manager, go to **Variables**
2. Find your GA Tracking ID variable, and click to edit
3. Under *More Settings* -> *Fields to set*

   - Add the Field Name `cookieFlags`
   - Set the Value to `samesite=none;secure`

   [image: Setting SameSite attributes for cookieFlags]
4. Save and publish a new version of your GTM configuration.

If done correctly this should resolve the browser warnings you are seeing.

Comment: What if you don't use Google Tag Manager? I just embed the script directly in my header.php file with 

      <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXX"></script>
      <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  
      function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
      }
      gtag("js", new Date());
      gtag("config", "G-XXXXX");
      </script>';

Comment: @GrayAyer Even if you aren't using `react-gtm-module` - by the looks of your src attribute there, it is still using GTM, and so the steps should be the same.